# Manage webgl state and issue sequential draw calls with three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to make a complex scene node, that would result in several draw calls and a state change in between, when encountered in three's `WebGLRenderer.render()` call.

Specifically I want to work with the stencil buffer, which is not exposed as a higher level API.

If I have

```
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( someGeom, someMaterial)
```

I need to have this happen before it gets drawn:

```
mesh.onBeforeRender = ( renderer , scene , camera )=>{
  //because there is no someMaterial.stencilOp = THREE.SomeStencilOp
  //i need to work with the gl context

  _gl.enable(_gl.STENCIL_TEST)
  _gl.clearStencil( 0 )
  _gl.clear( _gl.STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT )
  _gl.stencilFunc( _gl.ALWAYS , 1 , 1 )
  _gl.stencilOp( _gl.REPLACE , _gl.REPLACE , _gl.REPLACE )
  //...

}
```

Followed by more draw calls:

```
mesh.onAfterRender = ( renderer , scene , camera )=>{

  //more state 
  _gl.stencilFunc( _gl.EQUAL , 1 , 1 )
  _gl.stencilOp( _gl.KEEP , _gl.KEEP , _gl.INCR )

  //renderer.render( someOtherMesh , camera ) //this doesn't really work
  renderer.render( anotherSceneWithOtherMesh, camera ) //this is nightmarish 

  //more state for yet another call
  _gl.stencilFunc( _gl.EQUAL, 0 ,1 )
  _gl.stencilOp( _gl.KEEP , _gl.KEEP , _gl.KEEP ) 

  //renderer.render( mesh , camera ) //not a scene so it doesnt work
  renderer.render( proxySceneForThisMeshWithThisMesh, camera ) // :( i need to either bake the transformation, or somehow sync a copy of the scene graph down to this node

  _gl.disable( _gl.STENCIL_TEST )

}
```

What could I do with three, as is, r87 to achieve this with the least amount of headache?

I wish I could call some kind of `renderGeometryDirect` method that would just draw the geometry using the same node that the `onBeforeRender` or `onAfterRender` is being called, and through the same `camera` which is already being used in the top level `render( scene, camera)` call.

Or if it's just being called on `render(myObject3D, camera)`.

In lieu of this, i'm thinking about something that would manage creating these shadow graphs that would work with `render()` but i'm not sure what the best course of action is.

Comment: I probably don't see something here, but why can't you just do the three render-calls at the same level and the stencil-buffer controlling outside of that? Something like 1) preapre stencil 2) render scene with objects writing to stencil-buffer 3) render anotherSceneWithOtherMesh 4) render proxySceneForThisMeshWithThisMesh 5) disable stencil

Comment: I'm not sure how to best tackle creating those different scenes, and how to sync them if i want to be moving just the original node, if that makes sense? I need to have some kind of a management system that would be creating each one of these scenes, for each one of these "multi-pass" nodes i have.

Comment: Or a more convenient render call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an Idea, maybe you can use layers to achieve something like this (see [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/core/Layers.js) and [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/703aa286c546bb9e3da5645e7ba0971f5416de20/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L1233))? That should at least to allow you to specify subsets of the scene-graph to get rendered in a render-call.

So something like this:

```
_gl.enable(_gl.STENCIL_TEST)
_gl.clearStencil( 0 )
_gl.clear( _gl.STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT )
_gl.stencilFunc( _gl.ALWAYS , 1 , 1 )
_gl.stencilOp( _gl.REPLACE , _gl.REPLACE , _gl.REPLACE )

camera.layers.set(1);    
renderer.render(scene, camera);


_gl.stencilFunc( _gl.EQUAL , 1 , 1 )
_gl.stencilOp( _gl.KEEP , _gl.KEEP , _gl.INCR )

camera.layers.set(2);
renderer.render( scene, camera );


_gl.stencilFunc( _gl.EQUAL, 0 ,1 )
_gl.stencilOp( _gl.KEEP , _gl.KEEP , _gl.KEEP ) 

camera.layers.enable(1);
camera.layers.enable(2);
renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

Comment: I like this idea, but im worried that the number of channels may be limiting :( It seems that this way i'd have to assign a different layer for each of these nodes? Perhaps `.renderOrder` could do something similar to this, perhaps have each parentNode in a range from 1000 to 3000 for example, and then each of these other draw calls at N0 + 1, N0 + 2... ?

Comment: I thought more like one per pass, but then again I am not completely sure I know what you want to achieve, what the intermediate states of the stencil-buffer are and so on. Currently its limited to 32 layers, but it might be possible to monkey-patch the layers-implementation if you really need more (it's only used via it's methods iirc.)

Comment: Update on this. It actually works! I'm worried about the scene traversal with every render, but if doesnt update the matrices i think it can be quite useful.